# Helmet causing MERN app hosted on heroku cause ERROR: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following

Tags: reactjs, express, mern, helmet.js

I have hosted my MERN app on Heroku , but whenever I implement helmet in app.js file it's causing this issue.

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
// const cors = require('cors');
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoSanitize = require('express-mongo-sanitize');
const expressSanitizer = require('express-sanitizer');
const xss = require('xss-clean');
const hpp = require('hpp');
const compression = require('compression')

const authRouter = require('./routes/authRoutes');

const app = express();
// IMPLEMENT CORS
// app.use(cors());
// app.options('*', cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.header(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
   );
   if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
      return res.status(200).json({});
   }
   return next();
});

//SECURITY
// app.use(helmet());  <------causing issue.

const limiter = rateLimit({
   max: 100,
   windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,// 1 hour
   message: 'Too many requests from this IP, please try again in an hour!'
})
app.use('/api', limiter);

// Body parser, reading data from body into req.body
app.use(express.json({ limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '10kb' }));
app.use(cookieParser());
// Data sanitization against NoSQL query injection
app.use(mongoSanitize());
// HTML sanitizer
app.use(expressSanitizer());
// Data sanitization against XSS
app.use(xss());
// Prevent parameter pollution
app.use(hpp({
   whitelist: ['tags', 'likeCounts', 'commentCounts']
}));
// COMPRESSION
app.use(compression())
// logging 
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
   app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
```

App is running fine in local environment but helmet causes the ERROR:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-c8oXMAC5SpSNhKqLeKnZuBIrD93BdSvpZ47lOJrkmFE='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

I also tried fixing it by following this:

1. create a .env file in project root
2. Add variable as follows: `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false`
3. Build the project again and load the extension again.

But it doesn't help. Please guide me how can I fix it and also what would be best way to implement other security measures in my app?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Helmet maintainer here.

This is happening because of something called Content Security Policy, which Helmet sets by default. To solve your problem, you will need to configure Helmet's CSP.

[MDN has a good documentation about CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) which I would recommend reading for background. After that, take a look at [Helmet's README](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/) to see how to configure its CSP component.

To give some help specific to this question: this error is telling you that the `script-src` directive of your CSP does not allow inline JavaScript, and so it was blocked.

This is considered "inline" JavaScript:

```
<script>console.log('hello world!')</script>
```

This, however, is not:

```
<script src="/foo.js"></script>
```

There are several ways to fix this:

1. Add a hash or nonce to the inline `<script>` and use that in your CSP. See [this example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_inline_script) for help.
2. Refactor your app to avoid inline scripts entirely.
3. Update your CSP to allow unsafe inline scripts. You'd do something like this:

   ```
   app.use(
     helmet({
       contentSecurityPolicy: {
         directives: {
           ...helmet.contentSecurityPolicy.getDefaultDirectives(),
           "script-src": ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "example.com"],
         },
       },
     })
   );
   ```

   Note that this is considered unsafe.
4. Disable CSP. This is the most dangerous option so I don't recommend it.

   ```
   app.use(
     helmet({
       contentSecurityPolicy: false,
     })
   );
   ```

In summary: to solve your problem, you will need to tell Helmet to configure your CSP.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I ended up with this code -> 

`app.use(helmet({
   contentSecurityPolicy: {
      directives: {
         defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
         scriptSrc: ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'", "https://codersleague.herokuapp.com"],
         styleSrc: ["'self'", 'https://fonts.googleapis.com', "'unsafe-inline'"],
         imgSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.com'],
         fontSrc: ["'self'", 'https://*.com', 'data:']
      },
   }
}));` 

As I am using google fonts and cloudinary for image hosting I configured it accordingly.